# Pip in pycharm install packages in conda env and not in active venv inside project

Tags: python

i'm having a weird problem...

I can install packages using the built-in package manager in pycharm. But for some reason everytime i use "pip install (xx)" it is installing the packages in a conda env somewhere on my mac...

How can i solve this ?

I've tried the following:
close --> reopen pycharm //
deactivate and activate the venv //
Checked project intepreter is the right one (which it is...)

[image]

[image]

Comment: may be you installed them globally but you need them locally

Answer (score 1):

You're inside the virtual environment `venv`, while being inside the Conda `base` environment (note the `(venv)` and `(base)` to the left of your prompt). Conda is likely overriding your `venv`'s `pip`.

My bet as to why this is happening is that, during installation, you set Conda to autostart its `base` environment whenever a new terminal is open (be it inside PyCharm or not).

You can try to either:

- 1. exit Conda (with `conda deactivate`) and try `pip install` again (check to see that you're still inside the `venv` virtual environment).
- 2. install the packages directly from PyCharm's GUI - note the small `+` sign on the bottom-left of the package list. This won't solve the issue related to your terminal, but will function as a workaround for now.

Note that these aren't guaranteed to work, because you may have additional configurations on your system (either installed directly by you, or indirectly by Conda when you installed it).

Comment: hmm... pip isn't working when i run the command conda deactivate even though it's only venv which is active... It's weird because it is only this project